# How to automatically reflect changes of 2d layer in open layer into 3d layer of ol-cesium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gis, openlayers, arcgis

I am using
const ol3d = new OLCesium({map: ol2dMap}); // ol2dMap is the ol.Map instance
ol3d.setEnabled(true);
to render 3d view but after that any changes in 2d layer is not reflected to this 3d view.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve that

Comment: What are those changes in the 2D layer?

Comment: I add a geo json layer but that does not update in 3d model of ol-cesium but when i switch to 2d view it's present. The geoJson layer is rendered via vector layer. Please help if you have a work arund. If I render vector on 2d and then switch to 3d then it is present

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="https://cesium.com/downloads/cesiumjs/releases/1.70/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/css/olcs.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol-cesium@2.11.3/dist/olcesium.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #olCesMap {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #btnSwitchMap {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 2;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="olCesMap">
        <button id="btnSwitchMap" onclick="cesViewer.setEnabled(!cesViewer.getEnabled());">Switch 2D/3D</button>
    </div>
    <script defer>
        var controls = ol.control.defaults({
            rotate: true,
            rotateOptions: {
                tipLabel: "Reset rotation. \nUse Alt+Shift+Drag to rotate the map."
            }
        });
        var interactions = ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate: true, pinchRotate: true });

        // Declaring Zoom level to further view
        var zoom = 3;
        // Declaring Map center
        var center = ol.proj.fromLonLat([-96.41778916767144, 39.90201978025539]);
        
        var worldImagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
            maxZoom: 19
            })
        });
        worldImagery.set('name', 'tileLayer');


      
        //Map Creation
        var map = new ol.Map({
            controls: controls,
            //interactions: interactions,
            target: 'olCesMap',
            layers: [worldImagery, new ol.layer.Image({
                extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
            })],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: center,
                zoom: zoom
            })
        });
        //Cesium Viewer constructed based on Ol.Map
        var cesViewer = new olcs.OLCesium({
            map: map,
            sceneOptions: {
                mapProjection: new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection()
            }
        });
        //Cesium Viewer scene
        var scene = cesViewer.getCesiumScene();
        //Cesium Viewer enable
        cesViewer.setEnabled(false);

        //Cesium Viewer depthtest
        scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

try This I hope this is helpful for you !

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: It is nice source code to display 2d/3d map without token. Thanks!